# Zoom all the pages of ViewPager

Tags: android

I created on application with viewpager.Each pages consists of one imageView that is full screen.
I have implemented zoom on this image view. I want the zoom scale to be maintained when I scroll to next page in viewPager.
Please help me in implementing the feature.

Comment: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView use  TouchImageView and slove problem

Answer (score 0):

Store the `scaleX` and `scaleY` parameters of the `ImageView` as instance variables of the activity when the user zooms the image. Then in `onPageSelected` function of the `ViewPager` set the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties of the `ImageView` of the selected item.